# Converting/Mapping Keys to Values in Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array

```
    $fieldValues = [
        'brand' => 'brand_id',
        'mobile' => 'mobile',
        'customer' => 'customer_id',
        'points_value' => 'points'
    ];
```

Here is my field array which should get values from keys;

```
$fields = ['brand','points_value'];
```

So, here the output should be.

```
$fields = ['brand_id','points'];
```

I can create a function to convert them into values but just wanted to check if there is any function which can help me with it? I tried array_flip code but bad luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a single function that does that. However, a combination of `array_flip` and `array_intersect_key` does it:

```
$result = array_values(array_intersect_key($fieldValues, array_flip($fields)));
print_r($result);
```

Sidenote: If you want the keys preserved, then just remove the `array_values`. This just turns the resultant array into numeric indexed.

Or just plain ol' foreach should also suffice:

```
$result = [];
foreach($fields as $key) {
    if(isset($fieldValues[$key])) {
        $result[] = $fieldValues[$key];
    }
}
print_r($result);
```